# Installation of matconvnet-1.0-beta24 file in R2018b

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, scope, declaration, matconvnet

I want to run `mex -setup` in MATLAB, but firstly I must run `vl_compilenn` from MatConvNet version `matconvnet-1.0-beta24`. When I run `vl_compilenn` I get the error:

```
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2018b_1/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_alignr_pi8(__m64, __m64, int)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2018b_1/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:195:27:
error: '__builtin_ia32_palignr' was not declared in this scope
       (__v1di)__Y, __N * 8);
                           ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2018b_1/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_abs_pi32(__m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2018b_1/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:241:51:
error: '__builtin_ia32_pabsd' was not declared in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_pabsd ((__v2si)__X);
                                                   ^


Error in vl_compilenn>mex_compile (line 529)
mex(mopts{:}) ;

Error in vl_compilenn (line 490)
    mex_compile(opts, srcs{i}, objfile, flags.mexcc) ;
```

What can be done about this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc of gcc intrinsics](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html), you must compile with the flag '-mssse3'.

I would try to add this flag in the set of compilation flags `flags.mexcc`. I can't give you more details because the master has evolved from your version and the script `vl_compilenn` has evolved.